# Porting from php 5.6 to 8.2, how to express auto/init of multidimensional array?

Tags: php-8

This is now illegal if `$a` is not initialized  at each level.

```
$a["a"]["b"]["c"] +=1;
```

Does exists a syntax to force php8.2 to behave like php5.6 and so auto-initialize the `$a["a"]["b"]["c"]` to value zero, if and only if not already defined to each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Null coalescing operator `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (as of PHP 7.0), to use `0` is any element of the chain is not defined.

Example:

```php
$a['a']['b']['c'] = ($a['a']['b']['c'] ?? 0) + 1;
echo json_encode($a), PHP_EOL; // a.b.c = 1

$a['a']['b']['c'] = ($a['a']['b']['c'] ?? 0) + 1;
echo json_encode($a), PHP_EOL; // a.b.c = 2
```

Output:

```json
{"a":{"b":{"c":1}}}
{"a":{"b":{"c":2}}}
```

https://3v4l.org/sdX97